# Calling closure in map function

Tags: ios, swift, closures, map-function

> I have the code to convert UTC datetime to the local datetime based on a given address and this function is a closure. I want to call this function in a map function to change all my UTC time in an array of structs to local datetime.
> Here is my code for the converting UTC to local datetime.

```
func getTimeZoneFrom(address: String, completion: @escaping(_ coordinate: String?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { completion($0?.first?.timeZone?.identifier, $1) }
}

func calculateLocalDateTime(from date: String, identifier: String, using format: String) -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    
    if let date = formatter.date(from: date) {
        if let timeInterval = TimeZone.init(identifier: identifier)?.secondsFromGMT(for: date) {
            let localDateTime = Date(timeInterval: TimeInterval(timeInterval), since: date)
            return localDateTime
        }
    } else {
        print("Cannot get the date using the provided date format.\nPlease provide adequate date format.")
        return Date()
    }
    return Date()
}

func getLocalDateTime(date: String, address: String, completionHandler: @escaping ((Date) -> Void)) {
    getTimeZoneFrom(address: address) { (timeZoneIdentifier, error) in
        guard let identifier = timeZoneIdentifier, error == nil else { return }
        let localDateTime = calculateLocalDateTime(from: date, identifier: identifier, using: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

        completionHandler(localDateTime)
    }
}

func dateTimeUsingMediumFormat(provided dateTime: Date) -> String {
    return DateFormatter.localizedString(from: dateTime, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .short)
}
```

> Here is my attempt to apply this function in my map function.

```
struct LocationDateModel {
    var address: String
    var date: String
    
    init(address: String, date: String) {
        self.address = address
        self.date = date
    }
}

let models = [LocationDateModel(address: "Windsor, ON", date: "2021-01-07T19:27:54Z"),
              LocationDateModel(address: "Windsor, ON", date: "2021-01-07T21:54:54Z"),
              LocationDateModel(address: "Windsor, ON", date: "2021-01-08T00:36:56Z"),
              LocationDateModel(address: "Edmonton, AB", date: "2021-01-11T21:04:53Z"),
              LocationDateModel(address: "Edmonton, AB", date: "2021-01-12T15:56:19Z"),
              LocationDateModel(address: "Edmonton, AB", date: "2021-01-12T16:08:28Z")]

let modifiedModels = models.map { model -> LocationDateModel in
        var temp = ""
        getLocalDateTime(date: model.date, address: model.address) { (value) in
            temp = dateTimeUsingMediumFormat(provided: value)
        }
        return LocationDateModel(address: model.address, date: temp)
    }
```

> However, this is return an empty string for date as declared in temp which means its returning the declaration of the variable but not going into the closure. How can I approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have an asynchronous tree that needs a completion in all levels

```
var modifiedModels = [LocationDateModel]()
let g = DispatchGroup() 
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
models.forEach { model in 
dispatchSemaphore.wait() 
dispatchQueue.async(group: g) {
 g.enter()
 getLocalDateTime(date: model.date, address: model.address) { (value) in
    let temp = dateTimeUsingMediumFormat(provided: value)
    modifiedModels.append(LocationDateModel(address: model.address, date: temp))
    dispatchSemaphore.signal()
    g.leave()
 }   
 } 
}
g.notify(queue:.main) {
   print("All loaded",modifiedModels)
}
```

Edit: You can't as it directly as it's asynchnous

```
    var modifiedModels = [LocationDateModel]()
     
    getModified(models) { res in
        
        modifiedModels = res
        
    }
```

---

```
func getModified(_ models:[LocationDateModel],completion:@escaping(([LocationDateModel]) ->() )) {
    var modifiedModels = [LocationDateModel]()
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
    let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    models.forEach { model in
    dispatchSemaphore.wait()
    dispatchQueue.async(group: g) {
     g.enter()
     getLocalDateTime(date: model.date, address: model.address) { (value) in
        let temp = dateTimeUsingMediumFormat(provided: value)
        modifiedModels.append(LocationDateModel(address: model.address, date: temp))
        dispatchSemaphore.signal()
        g.leave()
     }
     }
    }
    g.notify(queue:.main) {
      completion(modifiedModels)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I have one more problem tho. Because this is asynchronous this ordering is out of place. Do you have any ideas on how I can order the modifiedModels according to the date variable.

Comment: Hey, how can I put this into a function and return the modifiedModels such that I can pass [LocationDateModel] as a function parameter and return modifiedModels